# How does the first benchmark ran always results in lower latency?

Tags: performance, cpu-architecture, intel, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I have a multithreaded application for which I am trying to improve the performance by changing which threads should be bound to which cores.

Firstly, I have some preprocessing step to figure out supposedly ideal thread-to-core mapping.

Following this, I am trashing data caches by writing to huge buffer, that effectively evicts the current data stored in caches. Then I run the baseline benchmark. For this benchmark, if there are `n` threads, threads will be bound to cores starting from `0` to `n - 1`, nothing fancy. I measure the elapsed time for the benchmark.

Afer this, I am trashing data caches again before running the second supposedly optimized benchmark. I call this "optimized" due to the fact that I will be doing a custom thread binding to cores according to the preprocessing of which I will not go into the details at the moment. I measure the elapsed time for the "optimized" benchmark again.

As a result, "optimized" benchmark turns out to be slower. This is okay, no problem. Maybe my optimization degraded performance. But then I swap the benchmark run order, and run the optimized one first. Then the optimized version becomes faster. The pattern here is that whichever benchmark I run first, it will be faster. I do not know how this is possible. Why is this happening?

Instead of data cache trashing step before each benchmark, I tried to do cache warming, but the same pattern persisted. I also tried to make the main thread sleep between each benchmark, still the same result.

Each benchmark run around 2.5 seconds, faster one resulting in around 20% lower latency execution. I tried running this application 20 times at least.

```
OS: CentOS-7
```

```
Server: Intel Cascade Lake with 56 cores, 2 sockets. 28 cores in each socket. 
I bound my threads to even numbered cores that are located in the same socket 
in order not to get QPI involved (there is interthread communication in this specific application).
```

```
Compiler g++11
Compiled with -O3.
```

Comment: A shot in the dark: CPU throttling? Do you let your CPU cool down (literally) between benchmark runs?

Comment: One of the things I tried was to sleep 5 seconds between each runs, but this did not help

Comment: To test the "CPU throttling" hypothesis, and more generally frequency scaling issues, you can set the frequency of all the cores to the base frequency and disable any *turbo* mode manually. You can also set a frequency lower than the base one (eg 20% smaller should be enough). I strongly advise you to track performance counters so to track cache events.

Comment: why the emphasis on cache events? also, which tool do you recommmend I use?

Comment: [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) lists a bunch of common pitfalls.  I wonder if your second run allocates fresh buffers that weren't already page-faulted in? (perf counters for page faults could tell you something if you attach separate `perf stat` instances for the first and second phases of the same program, e.g. via fork+exec and kill.)   Or conversely, if reusing buffers, maybe NUMA placement was good for the first run, bad for the second?